# How can I execute two if statements inside of a trigger at the same time in the output window?

Tags: mysql, triggers

```html
USE brendasdms;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS  Customers_Before_Insert; 

DELIMITER //

        CREATE TRIGGER Customers_Before_Insert
        BEFORE INSERT ON Customers
        FOR EACH ROW 
        
      BEGIN 
   IF(NEW.Email NOT LIKE '%_@%_.__%') THEN 
     SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '45000'
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT= 'The email column doesn\'t contain @ symbol or .(dot) domain'; 
           END IF ; 

           IF (NEW.Phone NOT REGEXP '[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}') THEN
                   SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '45000'
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT= 'The Phone Number Needs to be at least 10 digits long';
  END IF ; 

      END; //

DELIMITER ;



INSERT INTO Customers(FirstName, LastName, Email, Phone) 
              VALUES('Caroline', 'Wright', 'CarolineWrightrocketmail.com', '330-333-3448'); 
              
  
SELECT 
Customers.LastName, 
Customers.FirstName, 
Customers.Email 
 FROM  Customers
 WHERE Customer_ID= last_insert_id();
```

Hello Everyone.

I am trying to figure out can I execute two if statements inside of a trigger at the same time so that both error messages are display one after the other in the output window. Can I use a for loop or while loop to accomplish this task. Any suggestions would be great. Here is my code attached above.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the messages together before signaling:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Customers_Before_Insert
    BEFORE INSERT ON Customers
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_msg varchar(255) DEFAULT '';

    IF (NEW.Email NOT LIKE '%_@%_.__%') THEN 
        set v_msg = 'The email column doesn''t contain @ symbol or .(dot) domain';
    END IF;
    IF (NEW.Phone NOT REGEXP '[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}') THEN
        set v_msg = concat_ws('\n', v_msg, 'The Phone Number Needs to be at least 10 digits long');
    END IF;

    IF v_msg <> '' THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = v_msg;
    END IF ; 
END; //
```

You cannot signal twice in one trigger, because the signal ends the processing.  So, construct the message you want to construct.

Comment: Gordon Linoff -what does <> mean?

Comment: @User445555 . . . not equals.  That is the standard SQL operator.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff-This is not working! It doesn't recognize the v_msg variable

Comment: @User445555: Change `SET v_msg := '';` by `DECLARE v_msg VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT '';`.

Comment: @ wchiquito-Thank you for you help. This works, but if I wanted to display the messages in two different outputs not together on the same error message, how would I do that?

Comment: @User445555  . . . Sorry about that.  I wrote it originally with a session variable that doesn't need to be declared.